# Using two JNDIs in Spring Boot with JPA and entity manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an application which works fine with a single JNDI, but now I need to add a second one only for a single Entity. Here is my `application.properties`

```
#Datasources
spring.datasource.primary.jndi-name=jdbc/DS1
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.secondary.jndi-name=jdbc/DS2
spring.datasource.secondary.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#Hibernate 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
#Jackson properties
spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=NON_NULL
```

and my Spring main: `ScApplication.java`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "it.pippo.data.access.database" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "it.pippo.data.access.model" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "it.pippo" })
public class ScApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ScApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(ScApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

Inside the package `it.pippo.data.access.database` I have a DAO interface and a DAO facade which I use to perform operations on the datasource and in the `it.pippo.data.access.model` package I have all my table entities.
`DatabaseDAOFacade.java`

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DatabaseDAOFacade implements DatabaseDAOInterface {

    private final SessionFactory sf;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    protected Session getSession() {

        return sf.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseDAOFacade(SessionFactory sf, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.sf = sf;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T save(T o) {

        return (T) this.getSession().save(o);
    }
    .
    .
}
```

`Photo.java`

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PHOTO")
public class Photo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "PHOTO_REQUEST_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PHOTO_REQUEST_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "PHOTO_REQUESTS")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "UPLOAD_DATE")
    private Date uploadDate;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

How can I tell the application to look for the Photo entity into the second JNDI and not in the first one?
I have already tried a lot of different suggestions, but none of them worked for me. Also, I can't alter the structure of the application too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify what conection should be use in each DAO Respository.

You can use the @Qualifier annotation with the id of your datasource.

I've never done this in spring boot but with regultar Spring yes. I suppose your inyection of session factory should looks like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("primary") //Datasource conection bean id
    public DatabaseDAOFacade(SessionFactory sf, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.sf = sf;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
```

Comment: I defined a second DatabaseDAOFacade for the second JNDI, but even if I annotated it with the "secondary" @Qualifier it tries to find the Entity on the first one, in fact I receive  SQL Error: 942, SQLState: 42000, ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: seems that change the qualifier for "primary" should works?